# What is the rule of flow orientation when packet tunnel provider and app proxy provider run simultaneously on one mac endpoint?

Tags: c++, macos, network-programming, objective-c++, macos-system-extension

What is the rule of flow orientation when packet tunnel provider and app proxy provider run simultaneously on one mac endpoint?

There is two applications run on one mac endpoint, one app with app proxy provider, and another with packet tunnel provider. After test, it looks like the system flow will forward to random application. Is there any rules about that?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there is no information about this in official documentation.
There are, however, some answers [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705292) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713247).

In the end, Apple says, that if the packet tunnel provider is configured as per-app vpn, it will take all the traffic to itself, not giving it to other network extensions.

If PTP is configured as ip-based, the traffic should appear in order of providers registration: first in the one which was registered and activated first.

The only way to find the real answer here is to try, maybe asking Apple staff on their dev forums and creating bugs in their feedback system.